# Minification/Javascript exclusion

Tags: javascript

We have an iOS/Android web view and a regular website. The website uses a lot of JS code (600 kb minified) and the app uses less, but we are sending the all the js for the sake of development ease/speed.

The app only uses one module, but there is nothing in JavaScript to control which classes/functions there is access to, since all global variables are always accessible.

Javascript closures work in the reverse manner as is needed - they prevent outside calls from reaching inside the closure, but I would like, in theory, to prevent the inside code from reaching out.

The idea of enclosing the rest of our code in closures is great, except the refactoring is too large. A validator would also be quite useful, but I don't think one exists.

If I load partial js libraries, then it will break somewhere, someday and take a while to be noticed, since testing is mostly on the desktop app. If a separate version is created, likely the same will occur.

I guess I am micro-optimizing and this is impossible to easily do, but I would be interested if any good ideas.

Copied from another topic, this would be a great idea, except that all of the other global objects are still accessible.

```
var sand = function(window) {
var module = {
    say: function() {
        console.log(window.location);
    }   
};
return module;
}
sand({}).say(); // window.location is undefined
```